# Why do some public DNS records resolve to 127.0.01?

Tags: dns, localhost

As an example:

```
ad3.liverail.com
ad4.liverail.com
```

Both resolve to 127.0.0.1

I'm choosing to assume that this has been done on purpose for some (probably nefarious) reason, but can't quite work out what it'd be.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's look like liverail.com as been bought by facebook.  May be it's their decision to block any path to those hostnames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting a name to resolve to `127.0.0.1` is a quick and friendly way to take a name out of use. It will still resolve for people, so they know it's not just gone, but since it leads to localhost it will not cause any extra useless traffic on the Internet.